# How do we know if this following molecule is a superimposable mirror image or non-superimposable mirror image ? [See Image attached]

Tags: organic-chemistry, isomers

How do we know if this following molecule is Super Imposable mirror image or Non Super Imposable mirror image ? [See Image attached]

[image: Molecule]

Comment: How do you know your left and right hands are not superimposable? (Or maybe they are?)

Comment: Yes they are super imposable ? Because if we keep the mirror image of right hand on right hand , it's the same .

Comment: Super impossable mirror images means 2 mutualy mirror images, where you can identify one such an image with the other by its translation and rotation.  Involve your imagination.

Comment: @Nityoday Tekchandani  No, left and right hands are not super impossbale. You cannot formally by a geometry way identify the left(right) hand and its mirror image right(left), implying there is a mirror symmetry.

Comment: Okay, so according to what I understood, that a real object and it's mirror image, if they look same , they are super imposable , else non super imposable ? Also, then the question's answer would be Super Imposable ?

Comment: The real task is to let you learn why it is so,, not to tell you yes or no.

Comment: @Poutnik what if we rotate our hands 180° and then superimpose them, then it will be superimposible .

Comment: @user226375 No, they will not. They do not have a plane of symmetry.

Comment: user226375 Take in your thoughts your left hand. Turn it for its thumb to point to the left as the right hand does. Now, can fingers of the left hand band downwards as easily as fingers of right hand ? Are the nails on the same side ? And fingerprint areas ? etc...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Take 2 round, soft objects like potatoes or apples.
- Pin into each 4 pins of 3 different kinds ( 1 + 2 + 1 ),
  pointing to the most different directions.
- Call the 1st pin **bromine**, the 2nd one **hydrogen**, the 3rd one **ethyl**.
- Do the same for the other potato to be the **mirror image** of the first one.
- Try to rotate one of them to look like the other.
- If you succeed, they are superimposable.
- Now, replace one of the same pins on both objects by another -
  4th kind - of pins in such a way that they are still mutual mirror images.
- Try to match them the same way you tried previously.
- If you succeed, they are superimposable.

**The summary:**

- While there are 2 hydrogen atoms on a carbon atoms - or more generally, there are only 3 kinds of groups on a C atom - the groups/atoms of the same kind are interchangeble and you can rotate the molecule to match the mirror image.
- If there are 4 different groups on C atoms, you cannot make such a match.
- Said by other way, the former case has a plane of symmetry, the latter case does not.

Comment: Can we rotate the mirror image in x,y,z all the directions ?

Comment: Do you have in mind any reason why we cannot ? Imagine 2 pieces of LEGO. How would you determine they are identical ? You rotate them all the ways until you see they are the same - or not.

Comment: Okay, I tried this ,

Comment: Step one : https://m.imgur.com/gallery/1cLeqQd
Step two : https://m.imgur.com/gallery/Zyy2xfx

I can successfully rotate the mirror image to get it like the first one !! 

Hence I've come to a conclusion that these are super Imposable. 
Am I correct ?

Comment: for some reasons I cannot get the images. but if you talk about the fiirst 1+2+1 case, you are correct.

Comment: The links were wrong .. Try these :Step 1 : https://i.imgur.com/1cLeqQd.jpg  ..... Step 2 .... https://i.imgur.com/Zyy2xfx.jpg .. and I've understood the concept . Thank you

Comment: Ohkay , I just realised something, that , When we rotate the mirror image , the Wedge and Dash hydrogens replace each other, but they are with the same type of pin , hence that's okay ..? or it should be non super imposable if it's not okay to interchange wedge and dash hydrogens while rotating ..

Comment: Yes, until there are 2 hydrogens ( or more generally, there are only 3 kinds of groups on the C atoms, the groups/atoms of the same kind are interchangeble and you can rotate the molecule to match the mirror image. but if there are 4 different groups on C atoms, you cannot make such a match. Said by other way, the former case has a plane of symmetry, the latter case does not.

Comment: nice pins and table, but those carbons...  :-)

Comment: hehe those carbons are going from mental torture

Comment: About rotating to match the mirror image: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/109970/can-we-rotate-a-mirror-image-by-any-angle-to-check-if-it-is-superimposable

Comment: I will have a look, @KarstenTheis . Thank you ..

Comment: Note that  molecules can be achiral ( identical with mirror image ) even if it has 2 chiral carbon atoms ( atoms with 4 different substituents). as example see the meso-tartaric acid.

Comment: @Poutnik Alright :)